# How to play video from internal storage in ionic 5?

Tags: android, file, video, ionic3, ionic-native

I am developing one app in ionic, where online videos from server is downloading in

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files/Download/abc.mp4
```

But now i want to show that video in my app when device is not connected to internet.
How can it achieve??
What should be url need to give to video?
Thank you

Comment: Well use that file url i would say.

Comment: But your url is wrong. It should be: file:///storage/....

Comment: @blackapps Yes I have updated, Then how to show this url to videoview?